# Accessing Set-Cookie value from response.headers in axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, http-headers

I am using VueJS and Axios to send a request like this:

```
 axiosAPI.get('/login/flows', {params: {id: 'string'}})
            .then(res => {
                console.log('cookie', res.headers)
             }
```

In return server sends me this response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 646
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu,xxxx 13:56:21 GMT
Set-Cookie: csrf_token=Lxv3zynm1Fua0hU0/W1+R2w=; Path=/.ory/kratos/public/; Domain=x.y ; Max-Age=31536000; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Vary: Origin
Vary: Cookie
```

As you can see, server sends a csrf-token in Set-Cookies. but when I try to print out the headers I can not get and store the csrf-token. In addition, browser doesn't store the token at all in the storage section.

I need to use the csrf-token inside of this cookie but I don't know how I can do this?

Note: i don't have any access to back-end codes.

Comment: It's most likely because it's an HttpOnly cookie which is meant to be not accessible to javascript for security purposes. Please put back the image because it helps the question.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I updated my question with a sample from header response.

Comment: May I know what you are trying to do that you have the need to have the value of csrf token yourself?

Comment: I want to submit a login request and i need to add this csrf token into my payload's request

Comment: If you send a request from your browser, the cookies are automatically included unless you are sending it to a different domain and I don't think reusing csrf token is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

This approach works, but should be handled on a server side if it's HttpOnly cookie:

```
const res = await axios....;
const cookieName = '...';

const cookie = (res.headers['set-cookie'] as string[])
    .find(cookie => cookie.includes(cookieName))
    ?.match(new RegExp(`^${cookieName}=(.+?);`))
    ?.[1];
```

Comment: thanks. the short answer was enough for me. `res.headers['set-cookie']`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the axios-cookiejar-support.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cookiejar-support

A medium article showing how to use it.

https://medium.com/@adityasrivast/handling-cookies-with-axios-872790241a9b

Sample (getting cookie from a login page):

```
const axios = require('axios');
const wrapper = require('axios-cookiejar-support').wrapper;
const CookieJar = require('tough-cookie').CookieJar;

const jar = new CookieJar();
const client = wrapper(axios.create({ jar }));

const url = '<your url>';

const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('username', '<username>');
params.append('password', '<password>');
client.post(`${url}/Login`, params, {
  headers: {
    'Accept': '*/*'
  }
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: I use `axios-cookiejar-support` with Node.js and serverless to do a log-in and then do a sequent of request with the cookie session. It works good!

Answer (score -3):

Using this will get you the whole string for that header:

```
const cookieHeaders = res.headers['Set-Cookie'];
```

After that, you could split the string in an array with

```
cookieHeaders.split('; ');
```

In the array, you can then get the specific one you need.

Comment: This does not work. While the server is sending the cookie, it does not appear in the axios response headers object.